# Remove silence from audio in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, javascript-audio-api

I want to make a web app in JavaScript, where the user records voice from a mic and then the app trims the silent parts of the recording, so just the voice is left.

Note that silent parts may not be completely silent, because the sound is recorded from the mic, so there might be some background noise. But that noise will be much quieter, than the speech.

I need some guidance on how to do this. Some example of something similar would be nice. If not in JavaScript, than in any language, just so I can get an idea.

---

**EDIT:** I already handled the recording part using Web Audio API. I just need help with trimming.

Comment: maybe you should ask how to trim with audio api

Comment: no code to work with? a bit difficult to help.. show what you've done